# Getting Outlook 2007 to use the global address book?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, address-book

A computer at work has a local address book, that is, the one that the user has set up himself, and the global address book.

That is, the global address book is available, but apparently not used.

For instance, if the user creates a new email, typing in names in the "To"-field only looks through the user address book and not the global one. He can click on the "To"-button, manually select the global address book and then select contacts there though.

Is there a setting somewhere that has been corrupted or tweaked to make it behave like this? It's a bit of an annoyance to use these dialogs instead of just typing in the names and letting the autocomplete take care of the rest. For instance, using the meeting planner needs the right exchange accounts added, otherwise it won't show calendar information for the other attendants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find the auto-completion that pops up when typing names in to the **To** field is not doing an address book lookup - it's scanning a local cache that lists frequently/previously used contacts (from both global and local lists).

Here's a [MS support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287623) that explains how to reset the cache (in case of corruption, etc).
I don't know if it will help in your case, so obviously *take backups*.

You might also me interested in trying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> after typing the first part of a name in - it's the shortcut key for **Check Names** and will either replace the partially-typed name with a full match, if there's only one, or pop-up a box suggesting the various matches in the case where it finds several. *However*, I've got a feeling (not confirmed) that this only works with the global list, not local.