# Use Outlook 2010 Global Address List for Autocomplete?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, address-book

Outlook 2010 has a very nice autocomplete feature, assuming the person I'm contacting is a "recent contact." However, I would like the autocomplete list to pull from the "Global Address List" instead of my recent contacts.

To be clear, what I'm asking is NOT that when I hit "check names," the names I've entered get 'fixed' or completed. This works fine. What I'd like is that as I type names, it looks into the GAL and pulls down suggestions.

Is this possible? Perhaps with an Outlook addon?

Comment: Related/Possible Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/170793/getting-outlook-2007-to-use-the-global-address-book?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Xobni Plus for Outlook**](http://www.xobni.com/learnmore/plus/) (not the free edition) has an [**autosuggest**](http://www.xobni.com/autosuggest-outlook) feature, which indexes the global address book as well as everybody you have ever emailed or received as email from.

Answer (score 1):

[NK2Edit](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_nk2_edit.html) by NirSoft lets you edit NK2 files which include the Outlook Autocomplete file.

> In some circumstances, you may need to repair or modify the values appeared in the AutoComplete list, or you may want to remove unwanted email addresses and/or to add new email addresses. MS-Outlook doesn't provide any ability to edit this AutoComplete list, so this is where NK2Edit software can help you.

However, this involves modifying the Autocomplete list by hand (manually adding/removing addresses from the Global Address List). This isn't what I would prefer -- ideally, everyone in my GAL would be automatically indexed.